# What's the difference between Git Clone & Repo Sync

Tags: github

I'm a newbie in Android and while syncing Android sources I saw we used repo init and repo sync command whereas while syncing kernel source we use git clone.. Why do we use two different commands for a kernel source & android OS while they're on same website (github)? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

When repo sync is executed

- repo sync is equivalent to git clone if the project has never been synchronized.
- If synchronized once, then repo sync is equivalent to:

  ```
  git remote update
  git rebase origin/branch
  ```

where branch is the currently checked-out branch in the local project directory.